# <p:poll> causes "ERROR: MAC did not verify!" in server startup log

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, ajax-polling

I need to use polling for alerts. Since I add

```
<h:outputText id="alertNotif" value="#{alertController.number}"  />
<p:poll interval="3" listener="#{alertController.incrementNbrAlert}" update="alertNotif" />
```

I got an infinity of `ERROR: MAC did not verify!` when I start the server.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: And what do you expect from us?

Comment: How can i resolve this problem

Comment: Which JSF impl/version? There was a fix in Mojarra 2.2.4 related to this. And, how did you configure JSF state saving differently from defaults in web.xml?

Comment: "JSF 2.2" is a specification version. I was asking for the implementation name and its version. E.g. "Mojarra 2.2.4". You can usually find it in server startup log. Don't forget to answer the other question about state saving configuration too. If you have no clue what I was asking and/or what exactly to look for in web.xml, then just say so instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

This question has its time, but it may help another user to find a solution.

I had the same problem, my application did not have a problem until I integrated those lines of PrimeFaces, then my console jumped `ERROR: MAC did not verify!`, Investigate and it turned out that it was due to some kind of my project that was involved did not implement `Serializable`